# How to integrate SonarQube into jenkins pipeline for angular 8 project

Tags: typescript, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-web

I am trying to setup a pipeline script for an angular project with sonarqube. The pipeline process throws an error 'Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succeeded?' Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

```
I have added my project into sonar dashboard and generated authentication token. Also configured the jenkins.
```

Here is my code and confguration
   Jenkins -> configure system
    Name :SonarQube
    Server URL :  http://192.168.xx.xx:9000/
    Server authentication token : Sonarqube authentication token

```
Jenkins -> Global Tool configuration    
SonarQube Scanner
 name: SonarQubeScannerWeb
    install Automatically
JenkinsFile:   
  stage('SonarQube analysis') {
  steps {
    script {
       scannerHome = tool 'SonarQubeScannerWeb'
    }
    withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube') {
        sh "${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner"
    }
  }
```

}